# Kubuntu 15.04 - Mouse fails to drag-and-drop or select properly

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, 15.04, drag-and-drop

I just installed Kubuntu 15.04 and I'm facing a weird mouse issue.
Sometimes when I try to drag and drop a file/window or select some text my mouse looses control, (e.g. if I try to move a window it will move a little then loose focus, if I try to select some text at some point it will get deselected). It's like I would release the mouse button.

I want to mention that this is NOT a hardware problem, the mouse works perfectly fine on Windows or other distros, even on other flavors of Ubuntu 15.04.

I've been searching for a fix for hours, and can't make it work, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem with Kubuntu ever since 14.04 or so, I had the issue where I wanted to triple click to highlight a line and would have to instead double click and hold on the third click for the line to highlight.

I had a little success in adjusting the speed at which double-click is registered in the mouse/touchpad settings, I slowed mine down a little bit and it did help to a point.

I would research the mouse sensitivity config and see if there may be a solution there. Maybe pointer threshold?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but none of those settings seem to help at all(tested all of them with min/max values, even tried some combinations).